# Convert Expression<Func<TDerived, out TResult>> to Expression<Func<TBase, out TResult>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

All is said in the title, more precisely I am searching a way to convert an

`Expression<Func<TDerived, out bool>>` to `Expression<Func<TBase, out bool>>`,

with TDerived deriving from TBase.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know that you can directly convert.  What if the `Func<TDerived>` referenced a property of the derived class that was not part of the base class?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you want to "convert" the expression?

Comment: @Luaan I am working with Entity Framework, and I pass predicates as lambdas to a function that must treat both derived entities and base entities, but the base entity does not have the same properties/relationships of the derived.

Comment: @Luaan I meant predicates, not includes

Comment: Okay, in that case you'll have to go with Xanatos' solution - walk through the whole expression tree and fix it up. Or just separate the expression into two - one for base, and one for just the new properties in derived.

Comment: @SomebodyPleaseHelpme I think your real solution is to adjust the function accepting the expression accepting the base type to be generic, so that you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Given an `Expression` replacer like this one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

// A simple expression visitor to replace some nodes of an expression 
// with some other nodes. Can be used with anything, not only with
// ParameterExpression
public class SimpleExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> Replaces;

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { from, to } };
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Dictionary<Expression, Expression> replaces)
    {
        // Note that we should really clone from and to... But we will
        // ignore this!
        Replaces = replaces;
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(IEnumerable<Expression> from, IEnumerable<Expression> to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();

        using (var enu1 = from.GetEnumerator())
        using (var enu2 = to.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                bool res1 = enu1.MoveNext();
                bool res2 = enu2.MoveNext();

                if (!res1 || !res2)
                {
                    if (!res1 && !res2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!res1)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("from shorter");
                    }

                    throw new ArgumentException("to shorter");
                }

                Replaces.Add(enu1.Current, enu2.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        Expression to;

        if (node != null && Replaces.TryGetValue(node, out to))
        {
            return base.Visit(to);
        }

        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

now we can, given

```
public class Base
{
    public int ValueBase { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public int ValueDerived { get; set; }
}
```

and a

```
Expression<Func<Derived, bool>> exp = x => x.ValueBase == 0;
```

then

```
ParameterExpression parOld = exp.Parameters[0];
ParameterExpression parNew = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Base));

// Replace the parOld with the parNew
Expression body2 = new SimpleExpressionReplacer(parOld, parNew).Visit(exp.Body);

// Note that we have to rebuild the Expression.Lambda<>
Expression<Func<Base, bool>> expNew = Expression.Lambda<Func<Base, bool>>(body2, parNew);
```

This will produce a

```
Expression<Func<Base, bool>> exp = x => x.ValueBase == 0;
```

Note that if you want instead to do:

```
Expression<Func<Derived, bool>> exp = x => x.ValueDerived == 0;
```

to

```
Expression<Func<Base, bool>> exp = x => ((Derived)x).ValueDerived == 0;
```

then you need something like:

```
ParameterExpression parOld = exp.Parameters[0];
ParameterExpression parNew = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Base));
UnaryExpression convert = Expression.Convert(parNew, typeof(Derived));

Expression body2 = new SimpleExpressionReplacer(parOld, convert).Visit(exp.Body);
Expression<Func<Base, bool>> expNew = Expression.Lambda<Func<Base, bool>>(body2, parNew);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the inner expression. Something like

```
var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDerived));

Expression.Lambda<Func<TDerived, bool>>
(
  Expression.Invoke(innerExpression, argument),
  argument
);
```

Of course, depending on the direction, you might need an explicit cast on the argument to `innerExpression` - this is quite simple, just use `Expression.Cast`.

**EDIT:**

To accomodate for your edit, the inverted variant:

```
var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TBase));

Expression.Lambda<Func<TBase, bool>>
(
  Expression.Invoke(innerExpression, Expression.Convert(argument, typeof(TDerived))),
  argument
);
```

Note that this will obviously only work if the runtime type of the parameter is derived from `TDerived`.